# Opencart session deleting after virtual pos form post

Tags: php, opencart, payment-method

Opencart Version 2.0.3.1.
I have created a payment method to get payment from users.
Deleting disappear after sending data to the bank.

Form data sent to bank is below

```
$okUrl and $failUrl=https://www.xxx/online/index.php?route=payment/tumbankalar/bank_response
elseif($this->session->data["BankaPosTipi"] == "3d") 
{

        $okUrl   = $this->config->get('tumbankalar_donusURL');
        $failUrl = $this->config->get('tumbankalar_donusURL');
        $clientId = $this->config->get('tumbankalar_isbankasi_isyerikodu');
        $url = "https://sanalpos.isbank.com.tr/fim/est3Dgate";
        $amount = $toplam_tutar;
        $oid = $order_info['order_id']; 
        $rnd = microtime();    
        $storekey = $this->config->get('tumbankalar_isbankasi_storekey');
        $hashstr = $clientId . $oid . $amount . $okUrl . $failUrl . $rnd  . $storekey;
        $hash = base64_encode(pack('H*',sha1($hashstr)));
        $bolum=1;
        $form = ''; 
        $form .= '<form name="pay_form" id="pay_form" method="post" action="'.$url.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pan" value="'.$kart_numarasi.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cv2" value="'.$kart_guvenlik_kodu.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ecom_Payment_Card_ExpDate_Year" value="'.$kart_sonkullanma_tarihi_yil.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ecom_Payment_Card_ExpDate_Month" value="'.$kart_sonkullanma_tarihi_ay.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cardType" value="'.$kart_tipi.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="'.$clientId.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$amount.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="BOLUM" value="'.$bolum.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="oid" value="'.$oid.'"/>  
                    <input type="hidden" name="okUrl" value="'.$okUrl.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="'.$failUrl.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="rnd" value="'.$rnd.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="'.$hash.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="storetype" value="3d"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="tr"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="949"/>
                 </form>';
        $form .= '<script type="text/javascript">document.pay_form.submit();</script>';
        echo $form;
        //print_r($this->session->data);

}
```

I can access all sessions before the form is sent to the bank.

Callback Function is below

```
function bank_response()
{
   print_r($this->session->data);
}
```

But after bank site post data about the payment to the my site, the sessions are deleting.
Site is not working due to this error.

Data sent from the bank do not match the order data on the site.

I am logging back to the site because the sessions are deleted.

I can access the sessions when i try to pay this time.

I spent a lot of time to solve the problem but I couldn't figure it out.

Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

find in your module in `public function index()` part this line `$data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success', '', 'SSL');` or similar which contain `url->link('checkout/success'`  (after success this sessions deleting) and move it to your

```
function bank_response()
{
   print_r($this->session->data);
}
```

So this will be ran after your receive answer from bank. 
I'm not sure because here only part of your code, but this can cause your problem.